# Second monitor doesn't get recommended resolution

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have two monitors, the primary monitor plugged on HDMI port has a 1920x1080 resolution, and the secondary monitor plugged on DVI port is a 1600x900 resolution monitor, but the second monitor configuration shows the 1280x720 as maximum resolution available.
In others OS the second monitor gets the 1600x900 resolution as default.
I think it's a really good information to say, the computer has a Nvidia GeForce 750, and using the Ubuntu nvidia-* drivers instead of opensource drivers.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What other OSes have you tried this on?

Comment: Windows 10 and Windows 7.